# Docker with two web application containers

Tags: docker

I want to setup two containers for two web applications (GUnicorn/Django) . But I cannot map the port of the two containers to port 80 at the same time. How should I setup in this situation?

Comment: Setup a proxy (for example nginx, haproxy or Apache). Some of form of application routing is probably best advised when using docker.

Comment: Mark, adding an nginx container or setup nginx on the host machine?

Comment: Running nginx as a container or on the host is a matter of choice. The tricky part is creating the nginx configuration file. It makes sense to generate this. Lots and lots of examples, a quick google gave me this: http://jasonwilder.com/blog/2014/03/25/automated-nginx-reverse-proxy-for-docker/

Answer (score 2):

The point of the port number is so somebody else can find your service. It's like a name - if you were standing next to two people called Dave and you said "Dave", they would both answer, and it would get confusing. So the OS doesn't let you do that.

Your choices are:

1. Give each a different port number and have callers specify the right one.
2. Give each a different IP address and have callers specify the right one.
3. Add a third service on port 80 which can understand requests well enough to pass them to the right one.

You must make this choice. The trade-offs are that #1 and #2 place more overhead on the caller, while #3 is more work to set up and more load on the server.

#1 you would do by publishing to a different port. #2 by not publishing, and probably creating some routing rules. #3 needs another service, e.g. HAProxy.